# base_url not loading in codeigniter

Tags: css, codeigniter, base-url

I am using this in my `viewregistration.php` file

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $base_url; ?><?php echo $css; ?>reg_style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $base_url; ?><?php echo $css; ?>style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <?php $this->load->view('include/header');?>
    <?php $this->load->view('registration_view.php');?>
    <?php $this->load->view('include/footer');?>
</body>
</html>
```

And I am calling it in my conltroller as

```
$data['title']= 'Registration';
$this->load->view("viewregistration.php", $data);
```

And in my controller I am using

```
parent::__construct();

        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');

        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $this->load->model('systemdata');

        $this->data['css'] = $this->systemdata->get_css_filespec();
        $this->data['scripts'] = $this->systemdata->get_scripts_filespec();
        $this->data['base_url'] = $this->systemdata->get_base_url();
```

But the css file is not loading. It show some error like

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: base_url
```

and

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: css
```

What I am doing wrong?
I have used autoload url helper. But the result remains same.

Comment: Please show how you're loading your view file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variables aren't defined because you're not actually passing them to your view. `$data` and `$this->data` are not the same thing.

Here, you are correctly passing the `$data` array to your view:

```
$data['title']= 'Registration';
$this->load->view("viewregistration.php", $data);
```

But notice here how you're assigning your variables to `$this->data`, which never gets passed to the view:

```
$this->data['css'] = $this->systemdata->get_css_filespec();
$this->data['scripts'] = $this->systemdata->get_scripts_filespec();
$this->data['base_url'] = $this->systemdata->get_base_url();
```

You either need to assign your variables to `$data` or pass `$this->data` to your view.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think this line is necessary.

```
$this->data['base_url'] = $this->systemdata->get_base_url();
```

What you can do instead, is this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url($css.'reg_style.css'); ?>" />
```

base_url() is a CI function that gives you, the base url.

Sources: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html